# Problems with adding value to an array with array.append() in Swift

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, swift, append

in the moment we're programming a Swift App for iOS in which we want to get data of our JSON Website (MySql database) into the TableViewCell. The problem is by appending the text values of the strings for the label in the cell. Swift can import the JSON values into the name variable but I cant assign it to the text array for the cells. I havent no syntax errors, but the  data[0] Variable print sth. as "123". Why it is 123? The test Value is "Test". I don't now where the problem by appending the value to the array is, that the result is 123 after that. Please help.

Here is the sourcecode:

```
class listViewViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

var data:[String?] = []
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myUrl = URL(string: "");//Empty link for this question
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "lid=1";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        print("response = \(response!)")

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json {

                let Name = parseJSON["Name"] as? String
                print("\(Name)")//Test
                self.data.append(Name!)
                print("\(data![0])" as String)//123
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! listViewTableViewCell

    print("\(data[indexPath.row])")
    let dataCell = data[indexPath.row]        
    cell.listViewCell.text = dataCell
    return cell 
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? The value of data![0] should be a String of the Value in Name.

Comment: Try allocating data as var data = [String]()

Comment: Same problem, print("\(data![0])" as String) is "123", instead of the appended value of name "Test". From where is this result coming? I only added Name to the Value of data for the cells text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this because your array properties and data callback block parameter have the same name "data". in your code you user print("(data![0])" as String) instead of print("(self.data![0])" as String) => you have to add self.

then you can optimise your code like this (it's optional : it's just like a code review ;) )
try to do this 
- change your array type to String like this

```
var data = [String]()
```

- webService callback change your code like this :

```
 if let parseJSON = json {

            if let Name = parseJSON["Name"] as? String{
                print("\(Name)")
                self.data.append(Name)
                print("\(self.data.last)")//123
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you append to your data array you use self.data but you then print from data which is the parameter to the inner function. You add and print from different arrays.

Comment: Updated the answer